# Rails controller index exclude records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following index in workorder controller:

```
def index
   @workorders = Workorder.scoped
   @workorders = Workorder.where("created_at > #{params[:after]}") if params[:after].present?
end
```

How would I add the following so that it becomes an AND.  I want it to only include a workorder if maxsync <> 'E'.  Even if the parameter :after is present or not.

I tried this:

```
@workorders = Workorder.scoped.where("maxsynch != 'E' ")
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean you want a match if `maxsynch != 'E'` AND `created_at > #{params[:after]}` if `params[:after] exists, OR just match `maxsynch != 'E'` if `params[:after]` does not exist?

Comment: The first choice.  I always want to exclude the 'E' records whether there is an :after option or not.

Comment: Looks like @MrYoshiji has you covered. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain scopes like this:

```
def index
   @workorders = Workorder.scoped.where("maxsynch != 'E' ")
   @workorders = @workorders.where("created_at > ?", params[:after]) if params[:after].present?
   #examples:
   @workorders = @workorders.where(parent_id: params[:parent_id]) if params[:parent_id].present?
   @workorders = @workorders.active if params[:filter_active].present?
end
```

Comment: Thanks #MrYoshiji (again).